# How to use an included binary with node-webkit

Tags: executable, spawn, node-webkit

I'd like to use an embedded version of ffmpeg (or any executable really, it shouldn't make a difference) in my node-webkit project, so that the end user doesn't have to install the library in a location available in the $PATH prior to using the application. I would like to use child_process' ´spawn.bind´ to address the binary if possible. How can this be done if I know the relative path to the executable ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your system Linux? You could consider writing a shell script to wrap it and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I'll try this and let you know

Comment: Hi, so I tried the following and it worked : I got the application path with `fs.realpath` and thus provided the `spawn.bind()` method with the absolute path of the executable and this seems to be working. At least when I launch my app from the console (it is not packaged in an .app yet)